# Can I use onchange attribute for a cell of HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, database, html-table, event-handling

I have a table for which I pull the data from database. In each cell there in an edit image so when user clicks on it, there will be a pop up message and he can edit the data in the cell.( By using `prompt()` method). So I want to update the database whenever the data in a cell is changed, can I use onchange event attribute for a cell of a table? something like:

```
<td onchange="myFunction()">
```

if not, what kind of event attributes should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `onchange` (or rather the **change** event) is only used for input fields.

The proper way to do this is to let your JavaScript that prompts for input (using `prompt` is ugly btw, why not show a text field in the cell?) update both the cell's content and send the AJAX request to store the new value on the server.

Comment: so I will put an edit image in the cell and when user clicks on it, I will show an input box in the cell? but is it possible to show the current data of the cell in that  input box? if so, how can I do it? Thank you